# How to use both non-owning iterator and consuming iterator in a generic function in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

In Rust, we can use `.iter()` on various collection to create a non-owning iterator which returns references on a collection like Vec. We can also use `.into_iter()` to create a consuming iterator which then returns values moved out of the collection. There is no trait for `.iter()` like there is for `.into_iter()`, but we can achieve the same thing by calling `.into_iter()` on a reference to the collection.

For example, this function compiles fine:

```rust
fn test_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) {
    let i1 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create a non-owning iterator
    let i2 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create another one

    let i3 = vec.into_iter(); // create an owning iterator which consumes the collection

    // no more non-owning iterators can be created
}
```

I want to make this function generic. I want it to accept not just a Vec of i32, but also any other collection of i32 that happens to implement IntoIterator<Item=i32>.

Doing that seems simple enough, yet the following generic function no longer compiles.

```rust
fn test_generic<T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>>(vec: T) {
    let i1 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create a non-owning iterator
    let i2 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create another one

    let i3 = vec.into_iter(); // create an owning iterator which consumes the collection

    // no more non-owning iterators can be created
}
```

Compilation fails with the following error:

```
    |     let i1 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create a non-owning iterator
    |              ^^^^^^^-----------
    |              |      |
    |              |      value moved due to this method call
    |              move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
```

I don't quite understand this part of the error:

```
 move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy`
```

I'm not trying to copy a value of type T. I'm trying to copy a value of type **&T**, i.e. a reference to T, not T itself. I thought you could copy non-mutable references without issues. Why would it be required for T, not &T, to implement Copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a generic function, the only things exist for the type are from the bounds. If you specify `T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>`, then only `T` implements `IntoIterator`, `&T` does not. Of course, autoderef kicks in, dereferencing the reference but trying to move the value out of it.

If you want to specify that `&T` implements `IntoIterator`, the way to do that is as follows:

```rust
fn test_generic<T>(vec: T)
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = i32>,
    for<'a> &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a i32>,
{
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think you're on the right path, but the code still doesn't work.

`
90 |     let i1 = (&vec).into_iter(); // create a non-owning iterator
   |              ------ borrow of `vec` occurs here
...
93 |     let i3 = vec.into_iter(); // create an owning iterator which consumes the collection
   |              ^^^ move out of `vec` occurs here
...
96 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `i1` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `<&T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter`
`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments. But the gist of the issue is that because we've borrowed `vec` for the two borrowing-iterators, we can't consume it later. That makes sense, yet the first non-generic example works. There must be something else going on in my first example with regard to lifetimes that's not fully described by your type bounds.

Comment: @Daniel dropck. NLL knows that `Vec`'s `IntoIter` doesn't implement `Drop`, and so the vector can be moved if the iterator isn't used anymore as it won't be used during the drop of the iterator. But with generic iterator it can't prove that anymore. Apart from specifying the iterator as `Copy` (which force no drop, but generally iterators are not `Copy`), or scoping the iterator with references into a block, there is nothing to do.

Comment: I see. So if there was a way to specify that Drop cannot be implemented for the iterator (i.e. a negative trait bound), this would work, but since that's hard (impossible?) to do in current Rust, scoping is the best option to replicate the original non-generic function, am I right? Putting each line in its own block seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

The constraint you have written is for `vec` to be `IntoIterator`. This includes collections (like a `Vec`) which have the `.iter()` method to get non-consuming iterators, but *also* any other iterators. If `vec` is a stream where data are consumed and then immediately thrown into the void, your signature is perfectly matched (this is an iterator over `i32`), but taking a *reference to your stream* does *not* guarantee that you can iterate over references on `i32`: regardless of what you do with the integers received, you called the stream and lost the 'previous' value.

There are several solutions there:

- If you absolutely want to keep the signature the same, you can build a cache. You can be not really smart about it (collect the whole iterator into a `Vec` or something similar, and then do whatever you want with a known data structure, or do something finer where the iterator is called, and a cache is built incrementally, depending on your needs).
- Conversely, if you know that all your inputs are going to be *collections* (i.e. a bunch of elements, all available with random access, but don't care if it's a `Vec`, a slice, an array or something else), you need to express that in your signature:

```
fn foo<V>(v: V)
where for<'a> &'a V: IntoIterator<Item=&'a i32>,
      V: IntoIterator<Item=i32>
{
    let itr1 = (&v).into_iter();
    let itr2 = (&v).into_iter();
    for xi in itr1 {
        println!("{}", xi);
    }
    for yi in itr2 {
        println!("{}", yi);
    }
    for zi in v {
        println!("{}", zi);
    }
}
fn main() {
    foo(vec![1,2,3]);
    foo([1,2,3]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that your answer works around the Drop issue discussed in comments on the above answer by using for loops to essentially create a block and force a drop. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. You can run this on the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=880de3e1ce7303def63a68e7930b03f2; if you _remove_ the `for` loops in `itr1` and `itr2`, then you have your borrows of `v` still 'alive' when trying to consume `v`, and a compilation error. You can also get around the same issue with curly braces to force 'scoping' of the borrows: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=880de3e1ce7303def63a68e7930b03f2 (but that's not very useful)